# problems isolating a column based on what it's written in it in a csv file with Python

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook

I have a massive csv files with over 12 million rows and with 4 columns, the first column is just to put it in order from 0 to 12 million, the second one has the name of the region where this thing is, third one is a city (each city is a number) and 4th one has the number of visitors.
What I would like to do is plot the third and fourth column (one on the x and one on the y) but just for a certain region, I tried so many things to just read the part of the file that says 'Essex' but there is nothing that works, the second column Is called "region" the region i am interested in is 'Essex', any help? Thank you!

Comment: That sounds like an easy task? Open the file, give the file handler to a csv reader, iterate over the rows, whenever a row meets the requirement collect it (or write it directly in a file), then write the collected rows in a file which then only contains what you want. Did I miss something? Could you add some sample data to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the standard library called "[csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)". Something like this to get you going:

```
import csv

with open("name of csv file") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        # Check for Essex
        if row[1] == 'Essex':
            # Do whatever
            pass
```

The above example assumes there is no header line in your CSV file. If you do have a header, you can skip it like this:

```
with open("name of csv file") as csvfile:
    # Read and skip a header line.
    header = csvfile.readline()
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        # As above
```

or look into csv.DictReader().

Comment: Short addition: It's always a good practice to reduce the amount of indented code. So `if row[1] != 'Essex': continue`, instead of indenting the important code.

Comment: Thank you so much, this returns a series of separated values though, which means that when I try to plot row[2] against row[3] instead of a single big histogram with many columns I get many different histograms, how do I group all row[2] together as x and all row[3] together as y so that the first value of x goes with the first value of y and so on, so sorry for this I am very new to Python, thank you so much